# Hibernate Configuration.xml

Tags: xml, hibernate, configuration

Hi i have this exception on eclipse 
    at

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
15:07:49,089 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15:07:49,089 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration 15:07:49,089 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
at esik.telstudo.com.rest.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
15:07:49,089 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
... 121 more
15:07:49,090 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration from [Module "deployment.TelstudoAdmin.war:main" from Service Module Loader] 15:07:49,090 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198) 
15:07:49,090 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performL
```

And my hibernate.cfg.xml is like this

```
<session-factory>


   <!-- Pool SQLServer Local -->

  <property name="connection.datasource">java:/TelstudoAdmin</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!---->

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create
    --> 
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="esik.telstudo.com.core.Productos"/>
</session-factory>
```

please whats im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration Class is missing. Please add Hibernate jar to classpath and execute  your program again.